# Camera Changing Position When I Hit Play

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, game-development

so, I am trying to implement a FPS model and the camera is on that model's eye level.

Model is based on multiple objects in a hierarchy ( I have removed all the colliders from child objects)
The model has character control.

The camera is the child of that Model.

I have lined up everything correctly.
If I manually rotate Model, Camera will rotate accordingly and all if fine.

But when I hit play right as the simulation starts camera goes to rotation(0,0,0)

I don't understand what is happening. I tried to manually face the camera at the start method to Model's rotation. but that does not work.

**Before Play** 
https://i.stack.imgur.com/eKW8G.jpg

**After Play** 
https://i.stack.imgur.com/0ReY7.jpg

Mouse Look Script

```
public class mouselook : MonoBehaviour
{
    public float mousesens = 100f;
    public Transform playerBody;
    float xRotation = 0f;
    // Start is called before the first frame update
    void Start()
    {
        Cursor.lockState = CursorLockMode.Locked;
        // transform.rotation = playerBody.rotation;
    }

    // Update is called once per frame
    void Update()
    {
        float mouseX = Input.GetAxis("Mouse X") * mousesens * Time.deltaTime;
        float mouseY = Input.GetAxis("Mouse Y") * mousesens * Time.deltaTime;
        xRotation -= mouseY;
        xRotation = Mathf.Clamp(xRotation, -90f, 90f);
        transform.localRotation = Quaternion.Euler(xRotation, 0f, 0f);
        // transform.Rotate(Vector3.up * mouseX);

        playerBody.Rotate(Vector3.up * mouseX);




    }
}
```

Movement Script (IDK if it is relevent to this problem)

```
public class movement : MonoBehaviour
{
    public CharacterController controller;
    public float speed = 12f;
    public float gravity = -9.81f;
    public Transform groundCheck;
    public float groundDistance = 0.4f;
    public float jumpHeight = 3f;

    public LayerMask groundMask;
    Vector3 velocity;
    bool isGrounded;
    // Update is called once per frame
    void Update()
    {
        isGrounded = Physics.CheckSphere(groundCheck.position, groundDistance, groundMask);

        if (isGrounded && velocity.y < 0)
        {

            velocity.y = -2f;
        }
        float x = Input.GetAxis("Horizontal");
        float z = Input.GetAxis("Vertical");

        Vector3 move = transform.right * x + transform.forward * z;

        controller.Move(move * speed * Time.deltaTime);

        if (Input.GetButtonDown("Jump") && isGrounded)
        {
            velocity.y += Mathf.Sqrt(jumpHeight * -2f * gravity);
        }
        velocity.y += gravity * Time.deltaTime;
        controller.Move(velocity * Time.deltaTime);
    }
}
```

I suspect, this is going to some easy answer, which i have wasted hours on.

Problem is With this line, in mouse look script

```
 transform.localRotation = Quaternion.Euler(xRotation, 0f, 0f);
```

Comment: StackOverflow supports inserting images directly into the post. As a rule, we avoid linking to external sites where the content may disappear in the future, leading to an incomplete archive. Case in point: Your second image does not exist.

Comment: Thank you, I have fixed the second image issue.

Comment: Camera transform shouldn't matter if it's a child of the model.

Comment: Please edit the question and show the [translate gizmo](https://i.imgur.com/1OIYbnh.png) when you select `playerBody` before you hit play and when you select the gameobject `mouselook` is attached tobefore you play.

Comment: @Ruzihm, i am new to unity, are you asking for this ? https://imgur.com/a/SGwg0Pw

Comment: Well, maybe? I'm not sure what you did. You should just be able to now click the `Camera` gameobject in the hierarchy while the game is *not* playing. Anyway,   Why not just get rid of `transform.rotation = playerBody.rotation;`? Looks like you *don't* want the rotations to be the same...

Comment: i don't really understand, i have tried another script, which was based on Vector2 and same thing was happening. Yes I have edited that line. it didn't work for me.

Comment: I just want camera to be facing where the eyes of the Model is, and it works when game is not playing, when i rotate the Model and even after the play the movement is fine, camera is also moving proportional to Model, but just changes initial direction.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Had to set x-axis to a different value. and it works perfectly, did some changing in the movement script, changed some directions.

Mouse script

```
transform.localRotation = Quaternion.Euler(xRotation, 70f, 0f);
```

Movement Script

```
Vector3 move = transform.right * z + transform.forward * -x;
```

Thank you all.